# How can I sum arrays row-wise in Julia?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, julia

Suppose that I have a 2x2 array of the form:

[a, b

c, d]

Here a, b, c and d are numbers.

How can I calculate the column-wise sum in Julia? The result should be the column vector:

[a + b

c + d].

Comment: Use the `dims` optional argument with sum (and many other functions): `sum(M, dims=2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your data is

```
mat = [11 12; 21 22 ]
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 11  12
 21  22
```

the column sum is given by

```
sum( mat , dims = 2 )
2×1 Matrix{Int64}:
 23
 43
```

and you can get the row sum via `sum( mat , dims = 1 )`. To produce a vector from that you can do `vec( sum( mat , dims = 2 ) )` which gives `(2,)` that is a vector

Comment: And if you insist on the result being a vector instead of a `2x1 matrix`, you can add a `vec` outside: `vec(sum( mat, dims = 2))`

Comment: @DanGetz, yes, `vec(sum( mat, dims = 2))` will return a vector `size( vec( sum( mat , dims = 2 ) ) )` returns `(2,)` which is a vector